# How to use integers and booleans as input parameters in a jni function?

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I want to call in my java code a jni function with some integer parameter

**JAVA Code**

```
invokeNativeFunction(integer1, integer2, boolean1);
```

**C code**

```
jstring Java_com_any_dom_Eservice_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
                                                    jint integer1, // is it correct to put jint?
                                                    jint integer2,
                                                    jbool boolean1) {
}
```

How to use integers and booleans as input parameter in a `jni` function?

Comment: rather than write your jni method manually, use `javah` to generate the jni method from class is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the way you write native functions

Java

```java
private native void func(int length, boolean flag)
```

Now using the javah, generate .h file. It will have auto generated function declaration for you

```java
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_lgc_gstream_client_client_func (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jboolean);
```

Include this header file in some file and write the definition of the function. You can use jint and jboolean in code like normal int and bool in C++